# How to set permissions for multiple selected files in windows

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I know how to set permissions for one file. But I need to apply the same permissions to a huge number of files.

How can I do that without doing it one by one?

1. The files are in the same folder (If the solution includes subfolders also, much better).
2. I need to add `Total Control` for one specific user.

Comment: Are they all under the same folder/sub-folders?

Comment: Which kind of permissions?

Comment: I edit my question. Yes, to spikey_richie. Total Control for one user, to harrymc